# Secure peer to peer web server

Tags: open-source, security, web-server

I'd like to serve a client-side only web page with https and DNS.

I don't want to use any public hosts out of fear that the files will be tampered with.  To that end, I don't want to maintain my own physical server.

Is there an open-source application that can be used to serve web pages with the above requirements?

As examples, I have found [Freenet](https://freenetproject.org/), and [MaidSafe](http://maidsafe.net/) seems to claim that this feature will be available in the future, but Freenet doesn't seem to make it possible to serve pages from a user-selected domain much less from a CA verified SSL.

The requirements are:

1. Tamper-proof upload, storage, and web serving of web pages only: html, js, css, and images
2. Usage of a specified domain rather than one assigned
3. Usage of a CA verified SSL

Open source & linux are nice, but not required.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing here: your full list of requirements (must-haves, nice-to-haves; e.g. is scripting support or authentification needed), the OS it should run on. Also, where should it run on, if not on your server? Are you asking about a hosting service?

Comment: Several things in your requirements don't seem to make sense. I don't know if it's because there's something you don't understand or something you don't explain clearly. A “client-side only web page” would be a `file://` URL, so what have HTTPS and DNS to do with this? If you mean you want to run a web server on your own computer, then HTTPS and DNS are useless, you can just use `http://localhost/…`. Why do you want to bring SSL and DNS into play? Do you have a constraint on how you'll be accessing the web pages that makes the domain part of the URL important (e.g. are you testing something?)?